# применение скрипта одновременно для нескольких наборов элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер, есть подобный скрипт

```js
let $target = $('.good');
let hold = 500;
let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    if (index >=  $target.length)
      index = 0;
      
    $target.hide(); 
    $target.eq(index).show(); 
    index++;
  }, hold
);
```

```css
.good {
    display:none;
}
.container1, .container2{
border: 1px solid black;
}
.container2{
margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container1">
<div class="good">Текст 1</div>
<div class="good">Текст 2</div>
<div class="good">Текст 3</div>
<div class="good">Текст 4</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
<div class="good">Текст 5</div>
<div class="good">Текст 6</div>
<div class="good">Текст 7</div>
<div class="good">Текст 8</div>
</div>
```

сейчас он проигрывает появление и скрытие для элементов .good в container1 и container2 поочередно, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы появление и исчезание .good в конейтнерах происходило одновременно? Можно конечно просто дублировать код для каждого отдельно, но не думаю, что это верный вариант. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваш код выбирает все элементы `.good` в один список и поочередной их листает. 
Для вашего же случая надо в каждой "родительской" коллекции брать дочерние элементы с нужным индексом.  Например, с помощью селектора `nth-child`

```js
let $target = $('.good');
let hold = 500;
let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    if (index >  $target.length/2)
      index = 0;
      
    $target.hide(); 
    $(".container .good:nth-child(" + index +")").show();
    index++;
  }, hold
);
```

```css
.good {
    display:none;
}
.container1, .container2{
border: 1px solid black;
}
.container2{
margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container1 container">
<div class="good">Текст 1</div>
<div class="good">Текст 2</div>
<div class="good">Текст 3</div>
<div class="good">Текст 4</div>
</div>

<div class="container2 container">
<div class="good">Текст 5</div>
<div class="good">Текст 6</div>
<div class="good">Текст 7</div>
<div class="good">Текст 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вижу это я: обернуть в функцию, которая запустит таймер на одинаковых контейнерах

```js
let multiCount = (parentObj, childSelector) => {
  let $target = $(childSelector, parentObj);
  let hold = 500;
  let index = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    if (index >= $target.length)
      index = 0;

    $target.hide();
    $target.eq(index).show();
    index++;
  }, hold);
}

$('.container').each(function() {
  multiCount($(this), '.good');
});
```

```css
.good {
  display: none;
}

.container1,
.container2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="good">Текст 1</div>
  <div class="good">Текст 2</div>
  <div class="good">Текст 3</div>
  <div class="good">Текст 4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="good">Текст 5</div>
  <div class="good">Текст 6</div>
  <div class="good">Текст 7</div>
  <div class="good">Текст 8</div>
</div>
```